# How to connect AppsFlyer to Google Data Studio

Tags: python, api, looker-studio, appsflyer

I need to connect AppsFlyer  with Google Data Studio to get cost report.Only Partner Connectors prorvide connector with AppsFlyer,but it's not free. Could I make some script to connect it? And how to realize it?

Comment: this is too broad a question. i suggest you start digging in the documentation of google data studio, to see if they have an API, same for AppsFlyer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apps Script to build your own connector to AppsFlyer. Here's the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/).